# Trapping errors in PowerShell not working as expected

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am using a recursive call to Get-Children in order to get the total size of a folder/directory structure.  It works fine, but doesn't keep the errors in the ErrorVariable that I use, and from looking at documentation, it simply should?  Any ideas?

```
        [string]$fsoobjexist = Test-Path -Path $Folder
        $err=@() 
        If ($fsoobjexist -eq "True"){
            $err.clear
            if ((Get-Item $Folder) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]){
                $Foldersize = "{0:N2} MB" -f ((Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Folder -Force -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -EV +err -EA Continue  ).Sum / 1MB) 
                $logline = "$Folder,$Foldersize" 
                LogWrite $logline       

                Foreach ($Errors in $err){
                    ErrLogWrite "$($Errors.CategoryInfo.Category) $($Errors.CategoryInfo.Activity) $($Errors.CategoryInfo.Reason) $($Errors.CategoryInfo.TargetName) $($Errors.CategoryInfo.TargetType) $($Errors.Exception.Message)" 
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: But as it's recursive, I need to add to it, so it has to be +err, no?

Comment: Right you are. I forgot about that behavior of the variable parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've passed `+err` as an argument to the `ErrorVariable` parameter of `Measure-Object`, but it's likely the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet that throws the error.

Change it to:

```
$Foldersize = "{0:N2} MB" -f ((Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Folder -Force -Recurse -EV +err -EA Continue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1MB)
```

Comment: Ah, so add it before the pipe?

Comment: Add it to the command that throws the errors that you want to capture (in this case before the pipe symbol)

Comment: I thought it was something simple; I'm new to PS.  Thanks.